# How to move files from large document library to another library in sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010, powershell, document-library

i have document center site document library it has 53946 documents and i want to move 2000 files to another document library, when i try with openwithexplorer option its not working but another document libraries this option working 
 and i login to site with spfarm account and documentId feature is enabled.
[image]

Comment: Seems like you don't have permissions to do so. Question seems to be wrongly stated.

Comment: hi Tammy, i login to site with spfarm account, and this doc library as i said above has 53946  items, and i can able to open other document libraries , please read my post...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have at minimum Contribute access to the target library?  Is the Document ID feature enabled in the target site?  The Document ID is enabled by default in document centers and if the feature is not activated in the target location it may cause an error.  Also, the source library is over the list view threshold, and that causes lots of problems.

I'd confirm your access to the target and enable the Document ID feature.  If you still have issues then per the error message, contact your server/farm administrator and request they either export/import the files on your behalf or temporarily increase the list view threshold and attempt the move again.

Comment: hi there is another way to do this bcz doc lib has large no of files

Comment: Your server admin could help you with PowerShell export and import runs.

Comment: using powershell how can i do that